# How to stop Mythbuntu (Mythtv 0.27) running out of free disk space?

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

Previous mythtv versions had an option under the front end TV settings setup to control the amount of free hard disk space the system should maintain. I cannot find that setting in 0.27 and the mythtvbackend/ frontend is now constantly running into "out of disk space" problems.

Anyone now a work around or, if the setting still exists, where it can be found?

Comment: OK, found it. The setting has moved. In MythTV 0.27 it is 

Frontend > Setup > Video > General 

and then on the second page "Extra Disk Space (GB:)"

Thanks

Comment: Could you post that as an answer and then [accept it](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1141/44179) please? Thanks!

Comment: I'd gladly do that if I could see the "accept" button.

Comment: OK, having realised I need to "answer", it then says I can't accept it for an hour. Who thought of that? In any case, I'm away for a few days shortly so I guess it won't get "accepted" :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found it. The setting has moved. 
In MythTV 0.27 it is 
Frontend > Setup > Video > General 
and then on the second page "Extra Disk Space (GB:)"